# When should you use <article> as opposed to <ul>?

Tags: css, html

What determines whether one should prefer to use `<ul>` over `<article>`, or vice versa in a HTML document?

As an example I have a portfolio page with a list of items, which would be more appropriate?

Comment: My apologies, but this question is very unclear. What is considered a "portfolio page" and what content is being placed on the page. Elements shouldn't really be chosen by page type, but instead by page semantics. Whatever element is the best use case for a given purpose should be used. (i.e. `<ul>` with `<a>` are common for navigation lists while `<article>` and `<section>` are more common in stories and posts).

Comment: Since the answer is good, despite the vague question, the question itself should probably be edited to be more fitting to the site to avoid it getting closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element names form part of the semantic web/HTML, so you should use the one you deem most appropriate for your content, MDN is often a good resource to get an overview on what appropriate content may be, some suggestions from which are below.

Lists tend to include shorter, more concise often text only or very image-light content. It sounds like you likely want to look at the `section` or `article` tags.

**[Section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)**

> The HTML Section Element (`<section>`) represents a generic section of a
>   document, i.e., a thematic grouping of content, typically with a
>   heading.

[**Article**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)

> The HTML `<article>` Element represents a self-contained composition in
>   a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be
>   independently distributable or reusable, e.g., in syndication. This
>   could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry,
>   a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any
>   other independent item of content.

**[List (ul)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)**

> The HTML unordered list element (`<ul>`) represents an unordered list of
>   items, namely a collection of items that do not have a numerical
>   ordering, and their order in the list is meaningless. Typically,
>   unordered-list items are displayed with a bullet, which can be of
>   several forms, like a dot, a circle or a squared.